# Overlapping background bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css

So, on my web app's home page I have a birthday (mm/dd/yy) select fields however the drop down is being cut off by the next section of the homepage's background.

Here's the relevant CSS styling for the select:

```
.selectify .option {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 0 none;
    color: #999999;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

And an image:

[image]

How can I get the drop down to go over the secondary background section?

Cheers!

Comment: There is not enough information to answer. Try z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being given the link:

`.banner` has a style of `overflow:hidden;`. This is what is causing it to hide.
Delete it from the styles of `banner`.

Then, you have a class called `container middel-class`. Change this to just `middel-class`.

Then put `container` INSIDE `middel-class`. eg:

```
<div class='middel-class'>
  <div class='container'>
    .. <!-- rest of code as normal -->
  </div> <!-- end of container -->
</div> <!-- end of middel-class -->
```

Also, it's `middle`, not `middel`, but it doesn't really matter :P

Answer (score 0):

I cant say for sure without any code example of full place. This bug can be for few reasons

1.) Somewhere on a parent div (where located dropdown) you are using overflow:hidden - try delete it and see what happens

2.) also there is can be wrong z-index directly on the dropdown